# Websocket open error, websocket register error

Tags: webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I am facing web socket issue with https://appr.tc and unable to create or join the room.
Is there any temporary break down at the server end?

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its Apprtc signalling server issue. It will be back soon.

Permament solution would be to set up your own Collider server

[Refer](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/issues/440)