# WebSocket open error: WebSocket error

Tags: webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

We are using AppRTCDemo Android for audio/video call https://appr.tc 
Till last night all is working fine but now we are facing issue 
**WebSocket open error: WebSocket error.
WebSocket register error: WebSocket error.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zilyh.png)

Comment: Issue related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752796/websocket-open-error-websocket-register-error/43754154#43754154

Answer (score 0):

May be because of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7552.
Its resolved now, try again