# Turnserver showing WebSocket open error: WebSocket error after trying to join a room

Tags: websocket, ssl-certificate, webrtc, collider, apprtc

My app has 1:1 video calling feature and for that I set up my own turnserver. The turnserver was running perfectly till yesterday. When I try to call from app, turnserver rejects. I tried turnserver url from browser, it shows something like this, [image]

Immediately, I logged collidermain, it shows

```
root@<machine_name>:~# <timestamp> Starting collider: tls = true, port = 8443, room-server=https://<mydomain>.com
<timestamp> http: TLS handshake error from 182.160.105.186:43243: remote error: tls: unknown certificate
```

And this kept showing up everytime, my app try to connect with turnserver.

Thought, ssl certificates got something to do with it, replaced ssl certificates, tried re-installing collidermain, restarting google-cloud-sdk, turnserver, collidermain.  Still no luck.

Got two similar questions on stakoverflow.

[WebSocket open error: WebSocket error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753141/websocket-open-error-websocket-error), This is not chrome bug, because I got other two turnserver running perfectly fine at the time I am writing this and server health is pretty good

[Websocket open error, websocket register error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752796/websocket-open-error-websocket-register-error) This is not working too. I re-installed collider. No luck

**My question is, what is the root cause of this error and how to fix it?**

**System spces:**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- AppRTC code running with Google-cloud-sdk, version: 330.0.0
- Turnserver version: 4.4.3
- Signalling server: [collidermain](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/tree/78600dbe205774c115cf481a091387d928c99d6a/src/collider)

- Certificate issued with let's encrypt certbot

Comment: update: I destroyed the server and tried fresh install in another instance. Same result but  it's not giving ```TLS handshake``` error this time.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved! Here's what happend.

I copied the certificates issued by certbot into another directory `/cert/`
and in `turnserver.conf` file, I pointed certificate path to `/cert/` directory. So it worked fine for a while. Certbot certificates are valid for 3 months and it's renew automatically when validity expires. So, certbot renewed certificates and put it into `/etc/letsencrypt/live/:domain_name/`. `turnserver.conf` still pointing to outdated certificates resides in `/cert/` directory. That's why when I try to join a room, turnserver using outdated certificates and shows `TLS handshake error`

So, I just changed certificate path from `/cert/` to `/etc/letsencrypt/live/:domain_name/` in `turnserver.conf`, it's back online! Yay!!